# is there another way for latex table?

Tags: tables, overleaf

I'm a beginner in Latex and I want to put a really big table. I create one but I got an error saying `forgotten "}" or $` and I didn't understand what it means. Also when I want to add `\bullet` in the last rows the table disappear also the content after the table maybe because of that error. I don't know actually and I replace it with 0 for now.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[ht]
 \caption{Text} 
 \label{Text}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{|c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |} 
 \hline
 Text & Text & Text & Text & Text& Text& Text & Text & Text\\ 
 \hline

  Text &\bullet &  &  &   &  &  & & \\ \hline 
  Text &  & \bullet & \bullet&  &   &  &  &  \\ \hline 
  Text & \bullet & \bullet &  &  &  &  & & \bullet \\ \hline
  Text & \bullet & \bullet &  & \bullet &  \bullet & & & \bullet \\ \hline
  Text & \bullet &  &  &  &   &  &  & \bullet \\ \hline
  Text & \bullet &  &  &  &  \bullet & & & \bullet \\ \hline
  Text & \bullet &  &  & \bullet &   &  & \bullet & \bullet\\ \hline
  Text& \bullet &  &  &  &   &  &  &  \\ \hline
  Text & \bullet &  &  & \bullet &  &  &  & \bullet \\ \hline
  Text &  &  &  &  & 0 &  &  &  \\ \hline
  Text & 0 &  &  &  &   &  &  & 0\\ \hline
  Text & 0 &  &  &  &0   & 0 & 0& 0\\ \hline
  \end{tabular}}
   \end{table}
   \end{center}
```

Answer (score 4):

- Don't use resize box for elements that contain text. Instead choose an appropriate font size. If the table is too wide, try e.g. with `\small`, `\scriptsize`, `\tiny` etc.
- Don't put a center environment AROUND a floating table. Use `\centering` inside the table
- `\bullet` is only allowed in math mode. You need to warp it into `$...$` or use `\textbullet` instead

---

```
\documentclass{article}



\begin{document}

%\begin{center}
\begin{table}[ht]
 \caption{Text} 
 \label{Text}
 \centering
%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |} 
 \hline
 Text & Text & Text & Text & Text& Text& Text & Text & Text\\ 
 \hline

  Text &$\bullet$ &  &  &   &  &  & & \\ \hline 
  Text &  & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$&  &   &  &  &  \\ \hline 
  Text & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ &  &  &  &  & & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
  Text & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ &  & $\bullet$ &  $\bullet$ & & & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
  Text & $\bullet$ &  &  &  &   &  &  & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
  Text & $\bullet$ &  &  &  &  $\bullet$ & & & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
  Text & $\bullet$ &  &  & $\bullet$ &   &  & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$\\ \hline
  Text& $\bullet$ &  &  &  &   &  &  &  \\ \hline
  Text & $\bullet$ &  &  & $\bullet$ &  &  &  & $\bullet$ \\ \hline
  Text &  &  &  &  & 0 &  &  &  \\ \hline
  Text & 0 &  &  &  &   &  &  & 0\\ \hline
  Text & 0 &  &  &  &0   & 0 & 0& 0\\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
%  }
   \end{table}
%   \end{center}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As supplement to @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz nice anser (+1), a solution using `array` as table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Text}
    \label{Text}
\[
\begin{array}{|>{$}l<{$} | *{8}{c|} }
    \hline
Text & \text{Text} & \text{Text} & \text{Text} & \text{Text}
     & \text{Text} & \text{Text} & \text{Text} & \text{Text}        \\
    \hline
Text & \bullet &         &         &         &         && &         \\ \hline
Text &         & \bullet & \bullet &         &         && &         \\ \hline
Text & \bullet & \bullet &         &         &         && & \bullet \\ \hline
Text & \bullet & \bullet &         & \bullet & \bullet && & \bullet \\
\hline
Text & \bullet &&&         &         &       &         & \bullet    \\ \hline
Text & \bullet &&&         & \bullet &       &         & \bullet    \\ \hline
Text & \bullet &&& \bullet &         &       & \bullet & \bullet    \\ \hline
Text & \bullet &&&         &         &       &         &            \\ \hline
Text & \bullet &&& \bullet &         &       &         &  \bullet   \\ \hline
Text &         &&&  & 0    &         &       &                      \\ \hline
Text & 0       &&&  &      &         &       & 0                    \\ \hline
Text & 0       &&&  & 0    & 0       & 0     & 0                    \\ 
    \hline
\end{array}
\]
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]